# this.state.data.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an API call with React and the Facebook Graph API

The API is working fine but the map method is showing

`this.state.data.map` is not a function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

 class user extends Component {

    constructor(props){

        super(props);

        this.state={
            data:[123]
        }

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("facebook url")
          .then(response => {
              if (response.status === 200 && response != null) {
                this.setState({
                     data: response.data
                });
         } else {
           console.log('problem');
         }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
      render(){
          return (
                  <div>
                      {this.state.data.map((item,index) => {
               return (
                 <div key={item.id}>

                            <h1>{item.message}</h1>

                 </div>

             );
                  })}
                  </div>

              );
      }
    }
    export default user;
```

Comment: can you console.log(response.data) inside .then()?

Comment: Can you check if the response.data  returns an array?

Comment: You need to make sure the data you receive is an array. 

Also, Why is your initial state containing a number to what I see you are looping through array of objects i.e `item.message` & `item.id`. You should be seeing `undefined` on initial render until data is not resolved.

Comment: better: console.log(response) - there might not eben be data